# Link is only clickable on text in IE with absolute positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer

IE is being dumb once again. I have the following html and css:

```
<div class="tile">
   <a href="">this is a link</a>
   <img src="images/homepage-tiles/hello.jpg">
</div>

.tile {
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
}

.tile img {
    position: absolute;
}

.tile>a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

You should be able to click anywhere on the tile to hit the link, but in IE it only works if you click on the text within the link. The strange thing is that I also have a hover effect for the border of the `<a>` elements, and that works fine in IE from anywhere on the tile and reveals that the link is in fact the right dimensions. When I remove the absolute positioning then the link behaves normally but my layout gets screwed up.

And yes, perhaps I should just have the img as a background image in the link, but I have a bunch of these tiles and don't feel like giving unique names for every one with unique css attached to it. The point is, what I have should work, and it does work in other browsers.

Comment: Which versions of IE are you concerned about? How big is the image? Is the link supposed to be a sibling of the image?

Comment: All versions of IE. I mean 10, 9, 8 at least. No the link can't contain the image  because of the border hover effect. It will cause the image to shrink.

Comment: I don't see a hover style, but why not use `outline` instead of `border` if you're concerned about the box size changing?

Comment: That is not a solution to the present problem and the outline goes outside the box. I want an line around the inside of the box. If I really want to fix this problem I can just make the images background images. What I really want to know is how to make IE behave like it should.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure it slightly you could do something like this:

```
.tile {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}
.tile img {
   position: absolute;
   border: 0 none;
}
.tile p {
   position: absolute;
   z-index:9;
   left:70px;
}

<a href="#">
   <div class="tile">
   <p>this is a link</p>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />    
   </div>
</a>
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vpHSM/

Comment: Isn't it kind of wrong to have a `<div>` inside of an `<a>`? I'm hoping for a solution that is just a tweak to work around IE, not a restructuring of the whole page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it validates as acceptable markup but I understand you just want something that doesn't involve any restructure. Good luck!